# iPhone App defaults to iPad Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I created an iPhone App that will be serving as a Demo for a toolkit we've developed.
The thing is, whenever I open the project in XCode the Active Executable defaults to
`My Sample App - iPad Simulator 4.3`.

I know I can hold down Option and click the selector to move it to 'iPhone Simulator 4.3' but I'm looking for a way to ship this sample project so that it always opens up the iPhone simulator.

I've noticed that when change it to iPhone this is stored in under the project file/dir as a set of files with my username (e.g. `ohadpr.mode1v3` and `ohadpr.pbxuser`)

The `Target Device Family` setting is set to `iPhone`. I'm using XCode 3.2.6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to Xcode 4.

Otherwise, http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: there's got to be a way to configure this

Comment: you can configure it. But there is this bug that kills the setting on each close/clean/whatever.

Comment: From experiencing the bug, I noticed it happens every time you add a new file to the project. As in an image to your resource folder or if you add a new viewController

Comment: how can I 'freeze the moment' then? I don't mind copying some files aside while XCode is still running or smthng